# One endpoint of external API and multiple calls to it

Tags: api, external, ddos

Assume that we have only one endpoint of external API which gets id of one item and returns its data. Now we create app that needs to use it, but have a lot of ids of these items. Every ten seconds we have to call this API to update data of these items. Is there any solution not to ddos this external API by calling it thousands times every 10 seconds?

Comment: If the API is not controlled by you, then caching is pretty much the only thing you can do. So the answer is "don't call this API so often that it overloads"

Comment: Thanks for response! That’s right, the API is not controlled by me. So there is no other solution? Just the simplest one not to call it so often and cache data? But what if I have 1_000_000 items to get and I call API in loop every 10 minutes?

Comment: Minutes or seconds? Regardless, you have to do what you have to do. If the remote server doesn't like it, either query it less or ask them to add capacity.

Comment: I changed seconds to minutes to focus on 1_000_000 items in loop which call this API. Ok, so there are no technical solution besides making less queries, using cache or ask API owners to add capacity?

Comment: Not unless you control both ends. Sounds like you want to track realtime-ish updates. The approach you're describing (query status of an item every X seconds) is called "short-polling" and it's quite wasteful for both client and server. More efficient approaches are "long-polling" or some kind of "server -> client" persistent connection. These are pretty hard to implement if you don't control the server.

Comment: Thank you so much Sergio! It was so helpful and it ensures me that this problem is quite difficult when not owning server side of interesting data.